# Parsing JSON into an object with a defined 'schema'

Tags: javascript, json

I have a user specified JSON object that I'm attempting to process in the browser.

The problem is that it needs to match an existing object.

They can't accidentally:

- forget to include some fields.
- typo fields or deliberately add new fields.

Is there a way to handle this?

so basically if I have an object with foo and bar members, I want their defaults if the user's json is just {} ... and if they accidentally send something like {bart: "asdf";} (typo on 'bar') then I want it to generate an exception.

Comment: Check out http://json-schema.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
var default_object = { ... };
var allowed_keys = [ "key1", "key2", ... ];
var new_object = default_object.clone();
for (var key in json_object) {
    if (json_object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (allowed_keys.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            // Report error here
        } else {
            new_object[key] = json_object[key];
        }
    }
}
```

See [here](http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165) for how to write the `clone` method I used above. If you use jQuery, you could simplify some of this code by using `$.extend()`.

Comment: ah.. I was thinking of something like this but I was hoping for a native library that did it.

Comment: one other issue is that I need hierarchical / nested objects.  Like foo.bar.cat.dog.

Comment: `jQuery.extend` has an option to do recursive mergine. However, it doesn't do the validation checks -- that seems like an unusual requirement. Most APIs just ignore options they don't recognize.

Comment: The problem with this is when you typo a parameter.

Comment: It's a tradeoff. Being flexible allows composing widgets. For instance, datetimepicker.js is an extension of datepicker.js. It sends its options structure to datepicker.js, and it includes lots of options that the timepicker understands but the datepicker doesn't.